# Send Push Notification on wordpress Comment Published with onesignal

Tags: php, wordpress, webhooks, onesignal

using php to add action when there is a new comment in wordpress

i have tried this conditioning on a simple action and it works fine,

but here I get no results,

please someone else who understands better with this code, help me where did I go wrong,

is the problem a function within a function ? then what's the solution?

```
<?php 
function notify_comment( $comment_id, $comment_approved ) {
  if ( 1 == $comment_approved ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
      function sendMessages() {
          $tujuan = $comment->comment_post_ID;
          $permalink = get_permalink( $tujuan ); 
          $posttitle = get_the_title( $tujuan );
          $message = $comment->comment_content;
          $judul = "$comment->comment_author Mengomentari=> $posttitle";
          $logo = get_field('propil', $tujuan);

          $content      = array(
              "en" => "$message",
              "id" => "$message"
          );
          $headings      = array(
              "en" => "$judul",
              "id" => "$judul"
          );

          $hashes_array = array();
          array_push($hashes_array, array(
            "id" => "read-more-button",
            "text" => "Balas",
            "icon" => "https://ppg-magetan-timur.id/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/balas.png",
            "url" => "$permalink"
          ));
          array_push($hashes_array, array(
            "id" => "read-more-button-2",
            "text" => "Baca komentar",
            "icon" => "https://ppg-magetan-timur.id/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/lihat.png",
            "url" => "$permalink"
              
          ));
          $fields = array(
              'app_id' => "bbcd3d4f-6965-4b73-b82a-*************",
              'included_segments' => array(
                  'Test Segment'
              ),
              'data' => array(
                  "foo" => "bar"
              ),
              'contents' => $content,
              'headings' => $headings,
              'url' => "$permalink",
              'chrome_web_image' => "$logo",
              'web_buttons' => $hashes_array
          );

          $fields = json_encode($fields);
          print("\nJSON sent:\n");
          print($fields);

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
              'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
              'Authorization: Basic NzJmMWRjZDMtMmI3Mi00NT****************'
          ));
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

          $response = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);

          return $response;
  }
  $response = sendMessages();
  $return["allresponses"] = $response;
  $return = json_encode($return);

  $data = json_decode($response, true);
  print_r($data);
  $id = $data['id'];
  print_r($id);

  print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
  print($return);
  print("\n");

  }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'notify_comment', 10, 2 );
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function notify_comment( $comment_id, $comment_approved ) {
    if ( 1 === $comment_approved ) {
    
        $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
        $tujuan = $comment->comment_post_ID;
        $permalink = get_permalink( $tujuan ); 
        $posttitle = get_the_title( $tujuan );
        $message = $comment->comment_content;
    $judul = "$comment->comment_author Mengomentari=> $posttitle";
        $logo = get_field('propil', $tujuan);

    $end_point = 'https://api.webpushr.com/v1/notification/send/all';

$http_header = array( 
    "Content-Type: Application/Json", 
    "webpushrKey: 6361ccbba0dd06a67e9da0fa24d", 
    "webpushrAuthToken: 654"
);

$req_data = array(
    'title'         => "$judul",
    'message'       => "$message",
    'target_url'    => "$permalink",
    'icon'      => "$logo",
    'action_buttons'=> array(   
        array('title'=> 'Balas', 'url' => "$permalink"),
        array('title'=> 'Baca Lebih', 'url' => "$permalink")
    )
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $end_point );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($req_data) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;  
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'notify_comment', 10, 2 );
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).